# 'timestamp' messages appeared on my terminal, but i didn't code print('timestamp')

Tags: python, timestamp, ccxt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X5u8.png)I made my autobot for coin trade.
I'm using iterm2 terminal to operate my code.
But there's some problem I don't understand.

first I use the same fuction by changing parameter, symbolname etc.
but on the terminal window for A coin, there's only 'timestamp' message.
i can't tell if it is error or not because there's no error message
and i didn't code print('timestamp')
on the other terminal windows for other coin, there's no such a message.

I guess my explanation is not enough.
but if you have any idea about this kind of situations, please tell me.

I'm using python.
thank you already!!

sometimes, although i didn't change anytihng.
'timestamp' message was disappeared.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XesNZ.png)

```
enter code here
```

def runBot(symbol, second=int):
try:
subtitle = 'B'
fourth_interval = '30m'
symbol = symbol
path = path

```
    df_1 = callChart(exchange=exchange, symbol=symbol, interval='15m')
    df_2 = callChart(exchange=exchange, symbol=symbol, interval='5m')
    df_3 = callChart(exchange=exchange, symbol=symbol, interval='1m')
    df_4 = callChart(exchange=exchange, symbol=symbol, interval='30m')
    df_5 = callChart(exchange=exchange, symbol=symbol, interval='1h')
    df_6 = callChart(exchange=exchange, symbol=symbol, interval='4h')
    df_7 = callChart(exchange=exchange, symbol=symbol, interval='2h')

    n4hma2 = df_6.ma20[-1]
    n4hma6 = df_6.ma60[-1]
    n4hma8 = df_6.ma80[-1]
    p4h_rsi = df_6.rsi[-2]
    p4h_open = df_6.open[-2]
    p4h_close = df_6.close[-2]

    n1hma2 = df_5.ma20[-1]
    n1hma6 = df_5.ma60[-1]
    n1hma8 = df_5.ma80[-1]
    n1h_low = df_5.low[-1]
    n1h_high = df_5.high[-1]
    n1h_open = df_5.open[-1]
    p1h_rsi = df_5.rsi[-2]
    p1hma2 = df_5.ma20[-2]
    p1hma6 = df_5.ma60[-2]
    p1hma8 = df_5.ma80[-2]
    p1h_close = df_5.close[-2]

    n30ma2 = df_4.ma20[-1]
    n30ma6 = df_4.ma60[-1]
    n30ma8 = df_4.ma80[-1]
    n30_high = df_4.high[-1]
    n30_low = df_4.low[-1]
    n30_open = df_4.open[-1]
    p30_rsi = df_4.rsi[-2]
    p30_rsi = df_4.rsi[-2]

    p30_close = df_4.close[-2]
    pp30_close = df_4.close[-3]
    ppp30_close = df_4.close[-4]
    p30ma2 = df_4.ma20[-2]
    p30ma6 = df_4.ma60[-2]
    p30ma8 = df_4.ma80[-2]
    pp30ma2 = df_4.ma20[-4]
    pp30ma6 = df_4.ma60[-4]
    pp30ma8 = df_4.ma80[-4]
    ppp30ma2 = df_4.ma20[-4]
    ppp30ma6 = df_4.ma60[-4]
    ppp30ma8 = df_4.ma80[-4]
    p4_30ma2 = df_4.ma20[-5]
    p4_30ma6 = df_4.ma60[-5]
    p4_30ma8 = df_4.ma80[-5]

    n_price = df_1.close[-1]
    n15ma2 = df_1.ma20[-1]
    n15ma6 = df_1.ma60[-1]
    n15ma8 = df_1.ma80[-1]
    p15_close = df_1.close[-2]
    p15_open = df_1.open[-2]
    n15_high = df_1.high[-1]
    n15_low = df_1.low[-1]
    p15ma2 = df_1.ma20[-2]
    p15ma6 = df_1.ma60[-2]
    p15ma8 = df_1.ma80[-2]

    n5ma2 = df_2.ma20[-1]
    n5ma6 = df_2.ma60[-1]
    n5ma8 = df_2.ma80[-1]
    n5_high = df_2.high[-1]
    n5_low = df_2.low[-1]
    p5ma2 = df_2.ma20[-2]
    p5ma6 = df_2.ma60[-2]
    p5ma8 = df_2.ma80[-2]
    p5_close = df_2.close[-2]

    n1ma2 = df_3.ma20[-1]
    n1ma6 = df_3.ma60[-1]
    n1ma8 = df_3.ma80[-1]
    p1m_close = df_3.close[-2]
    p1ma2 = df_3.ma20[-2]
    p1ma6 = df_3.ma60[-2]
    p1ma8 = df_3.ma80[-2]

    n2hma2 = df_7.ma20[-1]
    n2hma6 = df_7.ma60[-1]
    n2hma8 = df_7.ma80[-1]

    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=9)
    now_date = datetime.date(now.year, now.month, now.day)
    now_time = datetime.time(now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
    what_day = now.weekday()
    timestamp = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(f'{now_date} {now_time}'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timetuple())
    mt4 = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
    mt4_date = datetime.date(mt4.year, mt4.month, mt4.day)
    mt4_time = datetime.time(mt4.hour, mt4.minute, mt4.second)
    total_balance = exchange.fetch_balance()['USDT']['total']
    total_balance2 = exchange2.fetch_balance()['USDT']['total']
    total_balance5 = exchange5.fetch_balance()['USDT']['total']

    print(colors.fg.blue, f'{subtitle}', colors.reset, colors.fg.green, f'{symbol}', colors.reset, f'{n_price}', colors.fg.yellow, f'{now_date} {now_time}', colors.reset)
```

Comment: Can you attach how your `timestamp messages` looks like on our terminal along with other outputs if possible some code currently you are uisng?

Comment: @Bhargav sorry I'm not good at using stack over flow. if you click enter image description here on the main script, you can see normal one, and abnormal one. thank you so much

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: How are we supposed to tell what's wrong if you don't post your code?